# excel function to retrieve cells from a table

Tags: excel

Just wondering if anyone can help - I have the table below and need to be able to retrieve the data where the machine count is >1 i.e the product has been done on more than 1 machine. 
So using the example product5 below in the highlighted cells I need a function that will return something like "product5 machine 1, product5 machine 4"

Thanks for reading! hope you can help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Power Query** it is an add-in for Excel 2010+ or by default in Excel 2016 known as **Get & Transform**. You can download and activate it easily. There you can connect directly your data and transform it with a lot of tools.

For you case it will be something like:

[image]